# use nest 2.2 on elasticsearch v 1.4.5

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using a server elasticsearch with a version 1.4.5,

```
 {
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Perun",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticdev",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.5",
    "build_hash" : "2aaf797f2a571dcb779a3b61180afe8390ab61f9",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-04-27T08:06:06Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

can i use a version 2.2 of nest to make querys to this server?

regards

Comment: No, you need to use NEST 1.x with Elasticsearch 1.4.5 - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net#compatibility-matrix the latest of which is 1.9.0 - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/1.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to use NEST 1.x with Elasticsearch 1.4.5 - github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net#compatibility-matrix the latest of which is 1.9.0 - nuget.org/packages/NEST/1.9.0 – Russ Cam 13 hours ago